# Python equivalent of Scala case class

Tags: python, scala

Is there any Python equivalent of Scala's Case Class? Like automatically generating constructors that assign to fields without writing out boilerplate.

Comment: What do you mean by "implementing Scala's Case Class"? Are you writing a Scala compiler in Python? What do you mean by "equivalent of Scala case class"? Which if the myriad of properties of a Scala case class do you want to be equivalent? The static type checking? What do you mean by "class variables"? Scala doesn't have class variables. What do you mean by "without creating class instances"? In Scala, every value is an object, and every object is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The current, modern way to do this (as of Python 3.7) is with a [data class](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557). For example, the Scala `case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)` becomes:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Point:
    x: int
    y: int
```

The `frozen=True` part is optional; you can omit it to get a mutable data class. I've included it for parity with Scala's case class.

Before Python 3.7, there's [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
```

Namedtuples are immutable, as they are tuples. If you want to add methods, you can extend the namedtuple:

```
class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):
    def foo():
        pass
```

Comment: And can ***deeply*** nested `dataclasses` or `namedtuples` be copied similarly to Scala's `case` `class`, e.g. like Scala can do using [lenses](https://www.slideshare.net/knoldus/scala-lens-an-introduction)?

Comment: @ecoe I don't know lenses, but you can always post another question to find out.

Answer (score 16):

**If you use `python3.7` you get data classes as `@dataclass`. Official doc here - [30.6. dataclasses — Data Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class CustomerOrder:
  order_id: int
  customer_id: str
  item_name: str

order = CustomerOrder(1, '001', 'Guitar')
print(order)
```

Make sure to upgrade python3 to python 3.7 or if you use python 3.6 install dataclass from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/)

In macos: `brew upgrade python3`

**While above data class in scala looks like,**

```
scala> final case class CustomerOrder(id: Int, customerID: String, itemName: String)
defined class CustomerOrder
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers about `dataclass` are great, but it's worth also mentioning that:

- If you don't include `frozen=True`, then your data class won't be hashable. So if you want parity with Scala case classes (which automatically define `toString`, `hashcode` and `equals`) then to get `hashcode`, you will need `@dataclass(frozen=True)`
- even if you do use `frozen=True`, if your dataclass contains an unhashable member (like a list), then the dataclass won't be hashable.
- `hash(some_data_class_instance)` will be equal if the values are equal (and `frozen=True`)
- From a quick empirical test, equality comparisons don't appear to be any faster if your type is hashable. Python is walking the class members to compare equality. So even if your `frozen` dataclass has all hashable members (e.g. tuples instead of lists), it will still walk the values to compare equality and be very slow.