# pyspark - how to preserve schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have two data sources, both have the same columns i.e. `id, product_name` coming as csv and json files. I hope to union these two data frames and write them out in parquet files. What would be a good way to enforce a schema first before writing it out? I read that parquet preserves the schema of the original data but I want to catch errors when data source has a bad record, for example `id` field should be an int but has a string. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to consider DataSet instead of Dataframe as DataSet ensures checks for data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a case class in scala and apply map operation on your RDD and convert it to DF using toDF(). Finally, you can write your DF to parquet file.

```
Assuming you have data as:
1,x
2,y
3,z

case class demo(id Int, name String)
val df = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(r=>demo(r(0).toInt,r(1))).toDF()
df.write.parquet("demo")
```

The above code is in scala

Python equivalent of Scala case class -
[Python equivalent of Scala case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342228/python-equivalent-of-scala-case-class)